# UIGestureRecognizer hooked up to UIVIew

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I'm a noob to iOS development (so please bear with me on this), and I'm trying to create a simple touch application with Xcode from scratch. I have spent a week on this, but I couldn't seem to find out what I have been missing so here I am, asking for some guidance :)

First, I created an empty application, then created a xib file (MainWindow.xib) and added a window object (Main_Window) to it. Then, I created a View object (Main_View) within this Main_Window, and added a label object (lblTitle) to this view. The Main_View object pretty much covered the entire Main_Window screen.

So, in short, the hierarchy of my MainWindow.xib is like this: Main_Window --> Main_View --> lblTitle.

Finally, I created a ViewController object (Main_View_Controller) with its "view" set to Main_View and its "rootViewController" set to "Main_Window".

In the project,

I subclassed UIView with "TouchEvent_View", hooked up to "Main_View" in the xib file.

I subclassed UIViewController with "TouchEvent_ViewController", hooked up to "Main_View_Controller" in the xib file.

In my AppDelegate.h,

I created an "IBOutlet UIWindow *window", hooked up to "Main_Window" in the xib file.

I created an object for my viewController and view classes.

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWindow *window; 
 @property (strong, nonatomic) TouchEvent_ViewController * myViewController;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) TouchEvent_View *myView;
```

In AppDelegate.m, I hooked up "MainWindow.xib" with myViewController:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{ 
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.myViewController = [[[TouchEvent_ViewController alloc]
                          initWithNibName:@"MainWindow" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];



    return YES;
}
```

In "Touch_Event_ViewController.m", I coded the viewDidLoad message as followed:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
  NSLog(@"Hi! ViewController's viewDidLoad msg sent!");

  TouchEvent_View * mView = [[TouchEvent_View alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];
  mView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
  [self.view addSubview:mView];
  [mView release];

}
```

In "TouchEvent_View.m", I instantiated a UITapGestureRecognizer object and hooked it up to a handler method as followed:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {

    NSLog(@"[TouchEvent_View initWithFrame] sent!");

    // Initialization code

    //-----------------------
    //Touch event declaration

    //Single tap
    UITapGestureRecognizer * singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SingleTap_Handler)];

    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    //singleTap.delegate = self;

    [self addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

}
return self;
}


-(void) SingleTap_Handler :(UITapGestureRecognizer *)GR
{
    NSLog(@"Hi! You just touched the screen!");

}
```

When I compiled and deployed the project into my iPad3, every thing worked just as planned until the Touch event, which didn't work.

I got the following messages printed out to the console window:

```
2012-08-26 14:03:59.589 Ex_TouchEvents_01[806:707] Hi! ViewController's viewDidLoad msg sent!
2012-08-26 14:03:59.593 Ex_TouchEvents_01[806:707] [TouchEvent_View initWithFram] sent!
```

But I did not see the "Hi, you just touched the screen!" message after I touched the screen. In addition, I didn't see the background of the View area set to blue either. So, I must have been missing something that was very simple. I have been googling all over the web, but I couldn't figure out what I missed. Would some body kindly point out what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have access to my Mac to test this, but I believe you're missing a colon in this line.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SingleTap_Handler)];
```

It needs to be:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SingleTap_Handler:)];
```

If a method takes any parameters, the colon(s) are part of the selector.

Comment: This is correct. The runtime will send a `SingleTap_Handler` message to the class, but there is only a `SingleTap_Handler:` method defined, so it will end up failing.

Comment: @Husker Good catch! Thank you. However, that still didn't resolve the issue. So, something else must be missing here as well.

Comment: @Husker In addition to adding the colon to selector(SingleTap_Handler:) like you suggested, I also created another "SingleTap_Handler" method which took no argument this time to see how it went. Unfortunately, I still had no luck. No message printed out when I touched the screen. For some reasons, that SingleTap_Handler method was not executed after UIView is initialized.

Comment: I just re-read your question and noticed something important--the blue background isn't showing up.  That means the view isn't making it onto the screen, which is why the gesture recognizer isn't being triggered.  The problem might be in the way you set up the view hierarchy.  For instance, there's no need to specify anything about `TouchEvent_View` in the .xib since you create the view programatically.  Try deleting all subviews of the main view in the .xib, then do something obvious like changing its background to red in viewDidLoad to make sure you've got that part right.

Comment: Thank you, Husker. That did it! After removing the Main_View, the blue back ground showed up (!), and when I touched it, the SingleTap_Handler function got triggered and I saw the message printed out to the console. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Erm, can you try putting:

```
self.userinteractionEnabled = YES;
```

in your init method?

UIViews by default is set to not respond to touch events so you have to enabled them first before your tap gestures work.

Comment: Thank you. I tried your recommendation, but that still didn't work. I also went into the xib file and made sure that the checkbox of  "User Interaction Enable" was checked as well.